# How to remove HTML Element from variable containing HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have got a jQuery var that contains HTML that I'm appending to a page.

I need to remove a HTML element before I append it to the page but I can't seem to filter it.

for example the variable contains;

```
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

I have tried filtering like this before I append:

```
var mydata = $(mydata).filter('.block1');
```

and

```
var mydata = mydata.filter('.block1');
```

but none of these work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `mydata` is already set somewhere? Have you tried `$("div").filter('.block1').remove();` or perhaps `$("div").filter(return $(this).hasClass(".block1")).remove();`?

Comment: Works well. http://jsfiddle.net/rns4h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter applied directly to string sometimes give string result, its safe to add element to DOM and then apply filters. Assign  html to some temporary element in the DOM, Get the filtered items from this temporary element and assign it to desired element.

```
$('#TemporaryElemntToAddHtml').html(mydata);

    $('#ElemntToAddHtml .block1').each(function(){
         $('#ElemntToAddHtml').append($(this));
    });

$('#TemporaryElemntToAddHtml').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  `.remove()`

```
$('.block1').remove();
```

OR

```
var mydata = $(mydata).remove('.block1');
```

Comment: This just returns mydata as null?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the .remove function?

```
  var mydata = $('<div class="block1"></div>
                 <div class="block2"></div>');
  mydata.remove('.block1');
```

Comment: I think you confused `selector` with `function`... Just to be correct.

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester, yes fixed

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it's got anything to do with the variable being passed back from an ajax request, but I can't see how this variable would be any different.

Comment: are you converting the ajax result to jquery element? ex: $(myresult)

Answer (score 0):

$.filter doesn't do what you think it does.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

I would try $(mydata).remove('.block1');

Answer (score 0):

Use the [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) native method to remove at the element index, and remove 1 item.

```
mydata.splice( mydata.filter('.block1').index(), 1 );
```

Note with that splice do not add mydata = mydata.splice(..) as that will return the removed element.

Otherwise use jQuery's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method as some people already said.